# SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108) Discord/python

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm using Pycharm and python 3.8 and latest version of discord. I tried to run this script but got this error. Can anyone help?

```
import discord

TOKEN = 'xxxxx'

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # we do not want the bot to reply to itself
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!hello'):
        msg = 'Hello {0.author.mention}'.format(message)
        await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

------ error below -------

> /Users/mellie/PycharmProjects/Dominations/venv/bin/python
>   /Users/mellie/PycharmProjects/Dominations/Domi.py Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/mellie/PycharmProjects/Dominations/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py",
>   line 936, in _wrap_create_connection
>       return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore  # noqa   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py",
>   line 1042, in create_connection
>       transport, protocol = await self._create_connection_transport(   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py",
>   line 1072, in _create_connection_transport
>       await waiter   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/sslproto.py",
>   line 529, in data_received
>       ssldata, appdata = self._sslpipe.feed_ssldata(data)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/sslproto.py",
>   line 189, in feed_ssldata
>       self._sslobj.do_handshake()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ssl.py",
>   line 944, in do_handshake
>       self._sslobj.do_handshake() ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get
>   local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/mellie/PycharmProjects/Dominations/Domi.py", line 24, in
>   
>       client.run(TOKEN)   File "/Users/mellie/PycharmProjects/Dominations/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py",
>   line 640, in run
>       return future.result()   File "/Users/mellie/PycharmProjects/Dominations/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py",
>   line 621, in runner
>       await self.start(*args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/mellie/PycharmProjects/Dominations/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py",
>   line 584, in start
>       await self.login(*args, bot=bot)   File "/Users/mellie/PycharmProjects/Dominations/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py",
>   line 442, in login
>       await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)   File "/Users/mellie/PycharmProjects/Dominations/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py",
>   line 256, in static_login
>       data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))   File "/Users/mellie/PycharmProjects/Dominations/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py",
>   line 160, in request
>       async with self.**session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as r:   File
>   "/Users/mellie/PycharmProjects/Dominations/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py",
>   line 1012, in __aenter**
>       self._resp = await self._coro   File "/Users/mellie/PycharmProjects/Dominations/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py",
>   line 480, in _request
>       conn = await self._connector.connect(   File "/Users/mellie/PycharmProjects/Dominations/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py",
>   line 523, in connect
>       proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)   File "/Users/mellie/PycharmProjects/Dominations/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py",
>   line 858, in _create_connection
>       _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(   File "/Users/mellie/PycharmProjects/Dominations/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py",
>   line 1004, in _create_direct_connection
>       raise last_exc   File "/Users/mellie/PycharmProjects/Dominations/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py",
>   line 980, in _create_direct_connection
>       transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(   File "/Users/mellie/PycharmProjects/Dominations/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py",
>   line 938, in _wrap_create_connection
>       raise ClientConnectorCertificateError( aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot
>   connect to host discordapp.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError:
>   (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed:
>   unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)')]
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: how you are accessing the internet ? If you are using some public wifi make sure the discord is not blocked by the host firewall. Thanks

Comment: it's the home internet.

Answer (score 27):

This github issue [here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/423#issuecomment-272093801). 
Says:

> Basically navigate to your Applications/Python 3.6/ folder and double
>   click the Install Certificates.command.

Try running this same program on 3.6 and run the install certificates command. This is likely to solve your issue

Comment: I tried that with 3.8/folder and double click. it didn't work.

Comment: Downgrade to python 3.5 or 3.6

Comment: I had this problem with pygame2 and python 3.9.  I double clicked on the install certificates command.  No errors.  Then it was all good.  Thx.

Comment: i had same issue and i navigated to python folder in my mac and i clicked the file named "Install Certificates.command" and it was fiexed. for my case it  was python 3.9 it should be pretty same for all other python 3 versions .

Comment: God bless this worked for me and I had Python 3.9

Comment: Wonderful, fixed the issue for me on Python 3.8

Comment: This fixed my issue when upgrading to 3.10 using the official installer.  Previously I had used homebrew, which seems to handle this step.

Answer (score 14):

I got the same error, but I fixed it by going to my Applications folder in my mac, going to python 3.9, and clicking on the install certificate file. It opened the terminal then it downloaded the certificate files.

Answer (score 2):

Run the below script(Works For Mac) in the python directory,

```
install Certificate.command
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `ssl=true&ssl_cert_reqs=CERT_NONE` to your MongoDB URI like this

```py
>>> uri = 'mongodb://example.com/?ssl=true&ssl_cert_reqs=CERT_NONE'
>>> client = pymongo.MongoClient(uri)
```

Most importantly the `ssl_cert_reqs=CERT_NONE`

Visit https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/tls.html for more information

Answer (score 0):

You don't use python 3.6 so the answer above is not the right one. I had the same problem and I figured out you could just use Anaconda, create an enviroment, install discord.py to the enviroment and since you use PyCharm, use the enviroment as the interpreter in it.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that this is an issue on discord's side, with no possible fix for the time being. I am running into the same problem with the [RedBot framework](https://docs.discord.red/en/stable/). They [recently stated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ksd66.png) that the "issue is related to Discord's root certificate and there is currently no recommended fix available."

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error while doing some scraping on a Linux distro:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.scraperapi.com', port=XX): Max retries exceeded with url: /account?api_key=MY_KEY (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)')))
```

I'm using Spyder with Python 3.8 and pyenv. For me, simply updating pip certificates solved this issue:

```
pip3 install --upgrade certifi
```

I was NOT using discord, but I thought others with this "1108" issue might want to see this potentially easy solution. Especially those on Linux. When I was searching for a solution, it seemed like this was a more common issue for Mac users.

Comment: Did not solve the issue for me. But always a good idea to update the certificates first. I think the Max retries is the problem...

Answer (score 0):

The real reason is the python library is not able to find the intermediate CA in the certificate chain.

For DISCORD:

DIGICERT BALTIMORE ROOT(Root) -> Cloudflare INC ECC CA-3 (Intermediate) -> sni.cloudflaressl.com

this is the certificate chain.

All the systems will have the root but not the intermediate. All you have to do is manually install the intermediate CA in your ca store

Comment: Could you provide some documentation supporting this? Is this always the case for every installation of Discord in every region? Thanks!

Comment: Hey, this is not Discord specific issue. Rather this is an application library issue and how Python or any other language is using the certificate. This is how the certificate chain works,

Comment: I wouldn't imagine that every certificate chain in existence goes through Digicert and two Cloudflare domains. It seems application-specific.

Comment: All I am saying, the ROOT certificate is already there in the machine, because the intermediate certificate is not there, the problem is occurring. I showed the example, as I manually verified the current certificate chain that Discord is currently using

Answer (score 0):

Use certifi along with urllib3

```
import urllib3
import certifi


url = 'https://blablablabla.com'
ssl_certs = certifi.where()
http = urllib3.PoolManager(ca_certs=ssl_certs)
resp = http.request('GET', url)

print(resp.status)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I tried updating the root certificate and even downloading the crt certificate file, but it still didn't solve it.
I think it's a code problem, not a system problem
So I used the following command to find the files currently read by SSL by default and check the corresponding files:

```
import ssl
paths = ssl.get_default_verify_paths()
print(paths)
```

I found that there was no corresponding pem file in this directory, so I modified it through export and pointed it to the correct file, which successfully solved the problem.

```
export SSL_CERT_FILE=/etc/pki/tls/cert.pem
export REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=/etc/pki/tls/cert.pem
```