# Python 3 & Slack Client : ssl.SSLCertVerificationError

Tags: python-3.x, slack

I'm trying to access Slack in python 3.8 but i'm unable to pass the first step.
Here is my code :

```py
import slack

slack_token="xoxp-*******-*******-*******-*******"
client = slack.WebClient(slack_token)

client.chat_postMessage(
    channel="XXXXXXXXXX",
    text="Hello from your app! :tada:"
)

print('hello')
```

and here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 936, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore  # noqa
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1046, in create_connection
    transport, protocol = await self._create_connection_transport(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1076, in _create_connection_transport
    await waiter
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 529, in data_received
    ssldata, appdata = self._sslpipe.feed_ssldata(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 189, in feed_ssldata
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 944, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)
```

### venv config:

```
pip3 freeze
aiohttp==3.6.2
async-timeout==3.0.1
attrs==19.3.0
certifi==2019.11.28
chardet==3.0.4
idna==2.8
multidict==4.7.4
pipenv==2018.11.26
slack==0.0.2
slackclient==2.5.0
virtualenv==16.7.9
virtualenv-clone==0.5.3
yarl==1.4.2
```

Comment: Side note, if that's your real slack access token, you should invalidate it and get a new one.

Comment: How about `pip install certifi` ?

Comment: already installed : see venv config

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scraping: SSL: CERTIFICATE\_VERIFY\_FAILED error for http://en.wikipedia.org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50236117/scraping-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error-for-http-en-wikipedia-org)

Comment: This seems to be the same issue as several other questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50236117, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52805115, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59411362, and probably others.

Answer (score 10):

Following instruction worked for me:

```
import ssl
import certifi
ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context(cafile=certifi.where())
client = slack.WebClient(token=os.environ['SLACK_TOKEN'], ssl=ssl_context)
```

Comment: which instruction is that? Tried this and got TypeError: Object of type SSLContext is not JSON serializable

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found a workaround by using this code

```
ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context()
ssl_context.check_hostname = False
ssl_context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

sc = slack.WebClient(slack_token,ssl=ssl_context)
```

Comment: Are you able to access it though `OAuth Access Token i.e. xoxp-` token ?

Comment: I wouldn't really recommend this because it turns off certificate validation entirely and makes your code susceptible to man-in-the-middle attacks.

Answer (score -3):

Believe you are using incorrect token in the `WebClient` class.
Try using Bot user access token in `WebClient`:

```py
slack_token="xoxb-*******-*******-******-******"
client = slack.WebClient(slack_token)
```

There are two types OAuth tokens:

1. **OAuth Access Token** - *starts with* `xoxp-`
2. **Bot User OAuth Access Token** - *starts with* `xoxb-`

Note: you can access the tokens of your app/bot from url - `https://api.slack.com/apps/{yourappid}/oauth?`.

> Slack OAuth Reference - https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth