# Failed to send a request to Slack API server: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed

Tags: python, ssl, slack-api

I am trying to create a basic slack app following this [tutorial](https://slack.dev/bolt-python/tutorial/getting-started). I have also created a slack app and generated the required tokens. But I am always getting below error. Please tell me where am I going wrong. My tokens seem correct.

```
Failed to send a request to Slack API server: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1124)>
Failed to send a request to Slack API server: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1124)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1350, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1255, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1301, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1250, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1010, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 950, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1424, in connect
    self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1124)
```

My app.py

```
import os
from slack_bolt import App
from slack_bolt.adapter.socket_mode import SocketModeHandler

# Initializes your app with your bot token and socket mode handler
app = App(token=os.environ.get("SLACK_BOT_TOKEN"))

# Start your app
if __name__ == "__main__":
    SocketModeHandler(app, os.environ["SLACK_APP_TOKEN"]).start()
```

Comment: Can you check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59808346/python-3-slack-client-ssl-sslcertverificationerror ?

Comment: thanks, @SuyashGauri I have added my app.py also in the question body. Does that give a clue what is wrong with my setup?

Comment: can you try using 'certifi' as mentioned in the answer provided in the above link?

Answer (score 1):

Anybody struggling with this on MacOS can look into: https://github.com/slackapi/bolt-python/issues/673

Comment: Just to add on this answer: 
"The issue was with my python installation. I went to the applications/ pythonfolder and clicked on the install certificate command it got fixed after that." 
-> that means to go in your folders on your machine and click on the file to install the certificate