# SSL Certificate Issue w/ Python Slack Bot

Tags: python, slack

I am attempting to write a simple Slack bot in Python, but am unable to connect because of an SSL issue. This has rendered all examples from tutorials I've found nonfunctional. I have also attempted several iterations on the solution using certifi as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59808346/python-3-slack-client-ssl-sslcertverificationerror) post with no luck.

Here is the relevant code:

```
import slack
import os
from pathlib import Path
from dotenv import load_dotenv

import ssl
import certifi
ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context(cafile=certifi.where())

env_path = Path('.') / '.env'
load_dotenv(dotenv_path = env_path)

client = slack.WebClient(token = os.environ['SLACK_TOKEN'], ssl = ssl_context)
client.chat_postMessage(channel = '#bot-channel', text = 'Hello World!')
```

And the error message:

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:997)>
```

Python version is 3.10.5

Answer (score 1):

`slackclient` is deprecated. You should use [the new slack_sdk](https://pypi.org/project/slack-sdk/) instead. The new sdk does not seem to require an SSL cert, so this issue is avoided entirely.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. Unfortunately, switching over to this new package results in the same error.

Comment: Can you update the question to show the new code & error?