# Certifacte verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1108)

Tags: python, certificate, discord

When trying to run my Discord bot I get this error:

```
raise ClientConnectorCertificateError(
    aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to
    host discordapp.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: 
   (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: 
   certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1108)')]
```

It just started happening out of nowhere and happens every time.

I'm using Python 3.8 on Windows 10.

What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: This is probably related to this [Sectigo root certificate](https://support.sectigo.com/articles/Knowledge/Sectigo-AddTrust-External-CA-Root-Expiring-May-30-2020) expiring. I'm still trying to figure out how to fix it but quick search shows that upgrading OS/OpenSSL/programming language versions may help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSL: CERTIFICATE\_VERIFY\_FAILED\] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (\_ssl.c:1108) Discord/python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59411362/ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certificate-verify-failed-unable-to-get-local-i)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To fix this:

- Go to discord.com with Internet Explorer (Ran as Administrator)
- Click the lock on the top right
- Click view certificates
- Install one

PS: If your antivirus is active for the web browser and this solution doesn't work, try disabling it and try again.

Comment: what does "go to discord.com with IE (ran as administrator)" mean? im kind of new to this

Comment: @doggosvsshibes It means to open Internet Explorer as administrator, and go to the website "discord.com"

Comment: when i open the certificates, the certificate is already there, and is valid

Comment: @doggosvsshibes have you installed that certificate to windows?

Comment: what is installing the certificate to windows?

Comment: @doggosvsshibes if you follow the steps it will give you an install button where you can install the certificate to windows

Comment: there's no button that let's me install a certificate though...

Comment: @doggosvsshibes if the install button is missing it's probably because you didn't run IE as administrator

Comment: This comment provides a detailed step-by-step process for installing the certificate
https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/4159#issuecomment-636386921