# How can I verify my SSL certificate for discord?

Tags: python, ssl, discord.py

Whenever I try to start my Discord bot, this Error Message comes up and I have no idea why my SSL certificate is expired, since if I visit Discordapp.com via Browser the certificate is still not expired (valid through Nov 2020).

How can I update this specific certificate?

I am on Win 10 (ver 2004)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 936, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1050, in create_connection
    transport, protocol = await self._create_connection_transport(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1080, in _create_connection_transport
    await waiter
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 529, in data_received
    ssldata, appdata = self._sslpipe.feed_ssldata(data)
  File "C:\Users\Fabian Mooslechner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 189, in feed_ssldata
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 944, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1108)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\bot.py", line 196, in <module>
    bot.run(TOKEN)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 640, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 621, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 584, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 442, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 261, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 165, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as r:
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 1012, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 480, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 523, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 858, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 1004, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 980, in _create_direct_connection
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 938, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise ClientConnectorCertificateError(
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host discordapp.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1108)')]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Certifacte verify failed: certificate has expired (\_ssl.c:1108)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62102897/certifacte-verify-failed-certificate-has-expired-ssl-c1108)

Comment: @Diggy. No I already tried this, my certificate is up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sectigo's AddTrust External CA Root Expired May 30th.

Install [this](https://crt.sh/?id=2835394) certificate to solve the problem. The download link is on the left hand side, half way down the page. Or you can just download it directly [here](https://crt.sh/?d=2835394).
You can find more information about the issue on Sectigo's Knowledge base [here](https://support.sectigo.com/Com_KnowledgeDetailPage?Id=kA03l00000117LT)