# SSL Certificate failure when attempting to connect a discord bot

Tags: python, ssl, ssl-certificate, discord, discord.py

I am attempting to program a bot for discord, but I have run into some SSL Certificate issues. I have tried downloading the certificate using Internet Explorer from www.discord.com to no avail. In addition, I do not have a Install Certificates.command in my Python build. I am using Python 3.8.3 and Pycharm, and here are the errors:

```
C:\Users\Reda\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Reda/PycharmProjects/untitled/bot.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Reda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 936, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\Reda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1050, in create_connection
    transport, protocol = await self._create_connection_transport(
  File "C:\Users\Reda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1080, in _create_connection_transport
    await waiter
  File "C:\Users\Reda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 529, in data_received
    ssldata, appdata = self._sslpipe.feed_ssldata(data)
  File "C:\Users\Reda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 189, in feed_ssldata
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\Reda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 944, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1108)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Reda/PycharmProjects/untitled/bot.py", line 16, in <module>
    client.run(TOKEN)
  File "C:\Users\Reda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 640, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Reda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 621, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Reda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 584, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\Reda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 442, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\Reda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 261, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "C:\Users\Reda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 165, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as r:
  File "C:\Users\Reda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 1012, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "C:\Users\Reda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 480, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "C:\Users\Reda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 523, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Reda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 858, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(
  File "C:\Users\Reda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 1004, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "C:\Users\Reda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 980, in _create_direct_connection
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
  File "C:\Users\Reda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 938, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise ClientConnectorCertificateError(
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host discordapp.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1108)')]

Process finished with exit code 1
```

```
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: We can't assist in debugging your program without at least a [Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have added an example

Comment: Run the `Install Certificates.command` (or maybe `.exe` or `.bat` for windows) that came with your python installation. Before running this, certificate authentication failed. After running it it works as normal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I verify my SSL certificate for discord?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62141402/how-can-i-verify-my-ssl-certificate-for-discord)