# Linux Python Discord.py Error: Unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: python, linux, ssl, discord, discord.py

I am trying to write a simple Discord bot in Ubuntu 22.04. I have written the code below:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands,tasks
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
# Get the API token from the .env file.
DISCORD_TOKEN = os.getenv("discord_token")
intents = discord.Intents().all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.',intents=intents)

ffmpeg_options = {
    'options': '-vn'
}

@bot.command(name='join', help='Tells the bot to join the voice channel')
async def join(ctx):
    if not ctx.message.author.voice:
        await ctx.send("{} is not connected to a voice channel".format(ctx.message.author.name))
        return
    else:
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()
@bot.command(name='leave', help='To make the bot leave the voice channel')
async def leave(ctx):
    voice_client = ctx.message.guild.voice_client
    if voice_client.is_connected():
        await voice_client.disconnect()
    else:
        await ctx.send("The bot is not connected to a voice channel.")


@bot.command(name="teiku", help="teikuuuuuuuu")
async def teiku(ctx):
        try :
            server = ctx.message.guild
            voice_channel = server.voice_client

            async with ctx.typing():
                voice_channel.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="ffmpeg.exe", source="teiku.com/teiku"))
        except:
            await ctx.send("The bot is not connected to a voice channel.")

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    bot.run(DISCORD_TOKEN)
```

Upon running the bot in a Python virtual environment, I receive the following error:

`aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host discord.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')]`

After some checking, including these links [here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/4159), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59411362/ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certificate-verify-failed-unable-to-get-local-i), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62108183/discord-py-bot-dont-have-certificate), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62160446/ssl-certificate-failure-when-attempting-to-connect-a-discord-bot), I determined that this error means the SSL certificates on my computer are not correct. However, nearly all answers are for Windows or Mac machines, not Linux, or involve using Anaconda (this is a straight Python install with no Anaconda and all packages used were installed from pip the old-fashioned way).

I attempted to use pip to update certifi, download the SSL certificates from Discord manually, and various other solutions to update SSL certificates or obtain them locally.

What I expected to happen:

- The bot will launch successfully and connect to Discord

What actually happened:

- The above-quoted error appeared, with no changes from each attempted solution

[Note: The link to teiku.com in the code above is not real. In my code it is a URL-shortened link to a .wav file, but this is not allowed on stackoverflow, so I replaced the link with another. It is not relevant to the question.]

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you figured out solution?

Comment: No. I used a totally different approach in the end.