# Followed a video tutorial but getting a lot of errors

Tags: python, discord, new-operator

So I was following a youtube video (link:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nW8c7vT6Hl4&t=757s) that teaches how to make a discord bot.

I followed all the steps but in the error box I am getting all of this, I am new to python and have no idea what any of these means, does anyone know how to fix this?

Follow my try:

```
[Command: python -u C:\Users\Me\Documents\bot\bot.py]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 936, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1050, in create_connection
    transport, protocol = await self._create_connection_transport(
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1080, in _create_connection_transport
    await waiter
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 529, in data_received
    ssldata, appdata = self._sslpipe.feed_ssldata(data)
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 189, in feed_ssldata
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 944, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1108)
```

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Me\Documents\bot\bot.py", line 10, in <module>
    client.run('NzE4OTYzNjcwMDU4NTMyOTA0.XtwhhA.3NFOWP4F7_HgsENW0rozGSX-pL0')
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 640, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 621, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 584, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 442, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 261, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 165, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as r:
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 1012, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 480, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 523, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 858, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 1004, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 980, in _create_direct_connection
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 938, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise ClientConnectorCertificateError(
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host discordapp.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1108)')]
[Finished in 0.975s]
```

Also here is the code that I used:

```
    >import discord
    >from discord.ext import commands

    >client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

    >@client.event
    >async def on_ready():
        >print('Bot is ready!')

    >client.run('token')
```

Comment: Seems that your certificate has expirated, look at the error: `SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1108)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Certifacte verify failed: certificate has expired (\_ssl.c:1108)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62102897/certifacte-verify-failed-certificate-has-expired-ssl-c1108)

Comment: Sorry I'm new to all of these I'm not entirely sure what that means, I'll have time to work with this a little tomorrow and I will get back and let you guys know if that was the problem.