# discord.py bot ClientConnectorCertificateError when run

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm taking part in a programming competition with my friends where the theme is Discord Bot Games.
I managed to program a basic start, but every time I try to run the code I have so far to test it I get an ClientConnectorCertificateError error.
Here is the code I have:

```
import os
import discord

from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext import commands

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user.name} has sucessfully connected to Discord!')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? (The token is in a separate file)

Here is the whole traceback:

```
Cannot connect to host discord.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)')]
```

Comment: Please post the *whole* traceback, not just a random part of ot

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński i added the traceback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows:

1. Go to start, type internet explorer. Run as admin.
2. Go do https://discord.com click on the padlock icon.
3. Click view certificates
4. Click install certificates, choose either user or local machine.
5. Click Place all certificates in the following store
6. Choose Trusted Root Certification Authorities

Check out this issue on github [issue](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/4159)

[aslo check out this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62102897/certifacte-verify-failed-certificate-has-expired-ssl-c1108/62104752#62104752)