# Certification not working for pycharm. Mac OS

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, python-3.8

I am creating a discord bot using pycharm 3.8. while running the code i get the error:

```
 SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108) Discord/python
```

Naturally I looked this up and found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59411362/ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certificate-verify-failed-unable-to-get-local-i), the solution is to run the install certificates.command. but while running this I get this error:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/certifi'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

Reading this, I used the same command in terminal (both in pycharm and the actual application) but followed by --user. This returns this message:

```
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (2021.5.30)
```

This leads me to think that I already have the correct certificates installed... but I still get the error stated at the start of this question. does anyone know how to fix this?

**[SOURCE CODE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ULSSdXT2w_BAV4aGdQoSyrthVXEQRYEm/view?usp=sharing)**

Answer (score 0):

The latest Python versions on MacOS come with their own private copy of OpenSSL. That means the trust certificates in the system are no longer used as defaults by the Python `ssl` module. To fix that, you need to install a `certifi` package in your system.

I see that you have done `pip install certifi --user`, but you also need to install `Certificates.command`.

Hence this should fix your issue: `open /Applications/Python\ 3.8/Install\ Certificates.command`

Comment: This just runs the old install certificates.command and returns the same error it did before