# SSL Certificate Verify Failure Error when sending an email using Python

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, gmail

I am trying to develop a python script to send an email using a GMail account and seem to be encountering an SSL Certificate issue. I have enabled the option to let less secure apps access my gmail account. Could anyone please help me to identify what I am doing wrong as I am getting this error:

ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997) - Detailed stack trace is below.

```
import smtplib, ssl


class Mail:

    def __init__(self):
        self.port = 465
        self.smtp_server_domain_name = "smtp.gmail.com"
        self.sender_mail = "some.email@gmail.com"
        self.password = "Password@123"

    def send(self, emails, subject, content):
        ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context()
        service = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(self.smtp_server_domain_name, self.port, context=ssl_context)
        service.login(self.sender_mail, self.password)

        for email in emails:
            result = service.sendmail(self.sender_mail, email, f"Subject: {subject}\n{content}")

        service.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mails = input("Enter emails: ").split()
    subject = input("Enter subject: ")
    content = input("Enter content: ")

    mail = Mail()
    mail.send(mails, subject, content)
```

Stacktrace is below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/prashanth/PycharmProjects/pythonTools/Mail.py", line 29, in <module>
    mail.send(mails, subject, content)
  File "/Users/prashanth/PycharmProjects/pythonTools/Mail.py", line 14, in send
    service = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(self.smtp_server_domain_name, self.port, context=ssl_context)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py", line 1050, in __init__
    SMTP.__init__(self, host, port, local_hostname, timeout,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py", line 255, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py", line 341, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py", line 1057, in _get_socket
    new_socket = self.context.wrap_socket(new_socket,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 512, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1070, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1341, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

My Environment:

```
MacOS Big Sur 11.6.5
Python : 3.10
```

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59411362/ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certificate-verify-failed-unable-to-get-local-i
specially installing certificate file

Comment: Thank you very much for your help....I searched on SO before posting but couldnt locate this particular solution.